# View Interpolation?

Tags: graphics

Given images from a certain viewpoints is there some software out there which can help me interpolate the views(i.e. Viewpoint interpolation software?).
Thanks,

Comment: so you want it to create panoramas but filling the gaps?

Comment: Do you mean something like panorama merging? Try Hugin (http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Many viewpoints or a single viewpoint with many angles? The distinction is important. If there are many unknown viewpoints then you may want to look at Bundler http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/

Comment: Maybe you mean something like the algorithm Google Earth uses to "fly" smoothly from one view to another? Are you talking about processing images/photos, or computing camera positions for rendering a scene?

Comment: @all:given 4 images from say 4 corners of a square I want to be able to interpolate views so that I can get views from places other than the 4 corners.

Answer (score 3):

*View Interpolation* is an illposed and very difficult problem, which in general has no optimal solution in real world scenarios.
This is because of several reasons, some of which include

- Wide Baseline Matching
- Disparity Estimation
- Occlusion Handling (Folds and Holes)

The quality of the outcome highly depends on your video footage, especially on how close together the cameras are.

Nevertheless, research is ongoing. *Dyer and Seitz* for example achieved nice results on constrained examples:

- http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~seitz/vmorph/vmorph.htm

*Stich et.al.* from TU Braunschweig showed some amazing results with their *Virtual Camera* system, which probably is the one thing, you are looking for:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqKTbyNoaxE

And finally, for soccer enthusiasts:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUK1UobhCX0
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UePrOp2s31c

As a starting point, look for **Image Morphing** and **View Morphing**.
If you want, I can provide some more papers on the topic.
Good luck! :)

EDIT: Also, if you're interested, here's my work on *Spatial and Temporal Interpolation of Multi-View Image-Sequence*.

http://tobiasgurdan.de/research/

Comment: +1 the answer and your paper! The paper states the source code is available on the webpage, but I can't find it. Help?